# how to avoid parent view controller rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation

I have parent viewcontroller - in portrait.
I have child viewcontroller - in landscape.
When child viewcontroller is dismissed parent viewcontroller remains in landscape- which it should not do. Please advice :=)
These are the settings:
[deployment info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSOYr.png)

My app delegate

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application    supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
   UIViewController* topVC = [self getTopController];
     if ([topVC isKindOfClass: [childVideoViewController class]]) {
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
     }
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIViewController*) getTopController{ UIViewController *topViewController =      [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topViewController.presentedViewController) {
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topViewController;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When You back from child view controller you should call 
Create a method in your child view controller and implement this

```
- (void)setScreenOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = (UIDeviceOrientation) orientation;
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: deviceOrientation] forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

Call this from child view before dismiss:

```
    [self setScreenOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: No - its not working - thanks for your effort @MasumBiswas- my parent viewcontroller is still in landscape after my childviewcontroller has called the app delegate.setscreenorientation(portrait). what am I missing ?

Comment: It's working for me. Please do directly without calling a function

Comment: Don't need to implement within app delegate to rotate your child view controller. You can do it within viewdidload like:    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:@"orientation"];